# Vertical scrolling in StackPanel without ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I am trying to fix a larger block of code written by previous colleague - it i some sort of report system, output is a table with data. My task was to freeze column headerson top when scrolling. As i am new to this, I made very simple table, to find out how datagrid works:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("prvni");
        dt.Columns.Add("druhy");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = "A" + i;
            row[1] = "B" + i;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        this.MainGrid.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
    }
```

By lots of searching, I found many topics, which recommended to get rid of ScrollViewer, as the freezed headers are in datagrid by default. This was the original part of code I modified:

```
        var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer()
        {
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto,
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
        };

        scrollViewer.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseWheelEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.MouseWheelHandler), true);
        var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        scrollViewer.Content = stackPanel;

        ...

        return scrollViewer;
```

And in another function, it was used/called as:

```
        var reportInfo = ((((sender as DataGrid).Parent as StackPanel).Parent as ScrollViewer).Parent as ReportOutputTabItem).Tag as ReportInfo;
```

Well - I removed the scrollviewer, and was returning it as StackPanel, however - now I cannot scroll at all. When I searched questions, how to add vertical scrolling to StackPanel, answers were "add ScrollViewer".

So - is there a way, how either make column headers freezed inside the ScrollViewer, or how to enable vertical scrolling in StackPanel without using scrollViewer? (and another possible solution might be to make the vertical size of StackPanel bit shorter, as there are mostly pages of results, but full page is still required to scroll a bit).

XAML part:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TabControl Name="MainTab" SelectionChanged="MainTabSelectionChanged" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Name="NavigationPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Height="23" Name="FirstButton" Width="40" Content="&lt;&lt;" Click="PageButtonClick" Opacity="0.75"/>
            <Button Height="23" Name="PrevButton" Width="40" Click="PageButtonClick" Opacity="0.75" Content="&lt;"/>
            <Label Height="23" Name="PageNumberLabel" Width="70" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="1/1"/>
            <Button Height="23" Name="NextButton" Width="40" Content=">" Click="PageButtonClick" Opacity="0.75"/>
            <Button Height="23" Name="LastButton" Width="40" Click="PageButtonClick" Opacity="0.75" Content=">>"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to put the DataGrid inside a StackPanel? The DataGrid has built-in scrolling support but since the StackPanel has infinite vertical space you can't use it within a StackPanel. Maybe you could show us some XAML?

Comment: Also make sure the DataGrid is not wrapped in a scrollviewer. (The default template of the DataGrid is actually a glorified ScrollViewer)

Comment: I put there bit of XAML. It wasn't wrapped in scrollviewer there, just the stackpanel. however, there are these button wrapped in the stackpanel, so I guess I cannot just remove stackapnel as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found solution to this:
Originally, the datagrid was wrapped in the StackPanel, and then in ScrollViewer.  I removed the ScrollViewer, and replaces StackPanel with Grid.

Now I have both vertical scrollbars, and frozen column headers.

I removed the entire

```
var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer()
{
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto,
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
};

scrollViewer.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseWheelEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.MouseWheelHandler), true);
var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
scrollViewer.Content = stackPanel;
```

and replaced with simple `var grid = new Grid();`

and all `stackPanel.Children.Add(dataGrid);` replaced with `grid.Children.Add(dataGrid);`

Comment: Good. Please mark your own answer as "the answer" to let everybody else know that this question has been solved.